# Finding intersections points of pairs of polar curves?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Find all intersections of the curves
$r=3^{(1/3)}\cos(\theta) , r=\sin(\theta)$

What I have done so far is to just put them equal to each other like this:

$3^{(1/3)}\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$, but how to solve the equation? Any tips?

Comment: Please consider adding Latex to format your questions.

Comment: The solutions are not nice angles. Square both sides, and use $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$. We get $3^{2/3}\cos^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, giving $\cos\theta=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2/3}+1}}$. Now we have to be careful. The last equation has $4$ solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. But two of them do not satisfy the original equation, they are extraneous solutions introduced when we squared. There are only two solutions, one in the first quadrant and one in the third.